# Displaying images from database in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django, and I am doing a simple web application that saves and displays products. But my problem is when I tried to display the product information I could display everything except the product image. You can see my code below.

settings.py in the static section:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

The main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('products/',include('products.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The models.py of the Products application:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from django.db.models.fields import CharField, DateField, DateTimeField
from datetime import datetime

from django.db.models.fields.related import ForeignKey, ManyToManyField

# Create your models here.

class Product(models.Model):
    categories = [
        ('Phone', 'Phone'),
        ('Computer', 'Computer'),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default='Nothing', verbose_name='title')
    content = models.TextField(default='Empty', null = True, blank = True, verbose_name='description')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2, default=0.0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/%y/%m/%d', default='media/photos/default/default_product.png',
                    verbose_name='picture')
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, choices=categories)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    class Meta:
        #verbose_name = 'name'
        ordering = ['-name']
```

And finally in the products.html:

```
{% block content %}
{% comment "" %}{{pro}}{% endcomment %}
    {% for product in pro %}
        <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
        <h1>{{product.content}}</h1>
        <h1>{{product.price}}</h1>
        </img src="{{product.image}}" alt="">
        <h1>-----------------------------------</h1>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.Note that to get image you have to access the `.url`

```
{% block content %}
{% comment "" %}{{pro}}{% endcomment %}
    {% for product in pro %}
        <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
        <h1>{{product.content}}</h1>
        <h1>{{product.price}}</h1>
        <img src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt=""/>
        <h1>-----------------------------------</h1>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```